# If a group G has only the trivial group and G itself as its subgroup, can we be sure that G has prime order?

Tags: group-theory

> It is given that the group $G$ has only two subgroups: the trivial group $\{e\}$ and $G$ itself, can we be sure that $G$ has order $k$ which must be a prime number?

I know that the reverse of this statement is true by Lagrange's theorem, but cannot be sure whether the above statement is true or not.

Comment: Have you seen Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: Hints: First establish that $G$ is cyclic. Next establish that $G$ must have finite order. Then conclude that $|G|$ must be prime.

Comment: @ThomasCredeur I have not learnt Cauchy's theorem, though I know Lagrange's theorem.  My textbook 'Algebra and Geometry' by A.F.Beardon does not cover Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I am struggling with the proof of finiteness. If $G$=$\{e\}$ then the proof is over. Otherwise let $g \in G$, then $G$ is the group generated by $g$. However I feel difficult to prove finiteness.

Comment: Suppose that $g$ above does not have finite order. Consider the subgroup $\langle g^{2} \rangle$. Show that it is neither the identity subgroup, nor all of $G$.

Comment: @ThomasCredeur : It does not seem to be given that the group is finite.

Comment: @Rescy_ $G=\{e\}$ seems to be a counterexample, unless you consider $1$ to be a prime number.

Answer (score 3):

Take a non trivial element $x$ of the group. Then the subgroup generated by this element $x$ is $\langle x\rangle=G$. Note that $G$ cannot be infinite because otherwise $G$ will be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$, and it's known that all subgroups are of the forms $n\Bbb{Z}$ (so an infinite numbers of subgroups). 
Now to prove that the cardinal is prime, suppose $n$ is not prime, that is, $n=rs$ for some integers $\ge 2$. What can you said about the order of $x^s$?

Comment: (Why the downvote ? did I do something wrong ?)

Comment: You have not proved the group $G$ is finite.

Comment: @Rescy_ Did you read my answer? Specially the second part?

Comment: You still haven't proved $G$ is finite, why should $x$ have finite order? See Geoff Robinson's comment above.

Comment: @Nex If G is infinite it will be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$..